# Is there a SQLite function similar to Pandas tail()

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite, group-by, tail

I am struggling to solve a problem in SQLite that was easy in Pandas. I have a large amount of data that is growing and has reached the point where the below call to a pandas dataframe results in a memory error (insufficient memory).

```py
    df_tail = df.groupby(['Phase', 'Cycle']).tail(time_for_avg)
```

I thought it might be wise to use a database in the form of SQLite to do this processing for me; however I am stuck at how to grab a portion of a chunk of data as I did with Pandas. I essentially want to grab the last 120 pieces (2 minutes) of data from a much larger (~10 hours) set that is defined by the groupby call in pandas. I have managed to get the groupby query in SQL like this

```
    SELECT 
        Phase, Cycle, 
        AVG("data1"), 
        AVG("data2")
    FROM 
        table
    GROUP BY
        Phase, Cycle
```

But my SQL ability is fairly low and that is where I am stuck. I can't think of a way to get the average computed by the groupby on only the last part of the data, as my SQL code computes the average of the entire data set returned by the groupby.

A description of the data is:
There are four Phases - Phase 1 to Phase 4, and these are repeated many time in the data set. The Cycle number is incrementing from 0 in 1's, so 0, 1, 2.... So Cycle 1 would be associated with Phase 1, Cycle 2 would be associated with Phase 2...Cycle 5 would be associated with Phase 1 again as the Phases repeat and so on. I would like the average for each Phase and Cycle to be stored in another table for results.

Any help or pointers would be welcome. Thank you.

## Edit July 16, 2020

Sorry if there was some confusion, this was written in a 'throw your hands up in despair' moment...

A better description of the data might be:

```
Cycle  |  Phase
1      |  phase 1
2      |  phase 2
3      |  phase 3
4      |  phase 4
5      |  phase 1
6      |  phase 2
7...
```

Each row in the above table has about 36000 rows (10 hours worth of data recorded every second). There is also 60 data points for each time stamp recorded.

```
Raw data
Row #  |  Cycle  |  Phase    |  data 1  |  data 2 ... data 60
1      |  1      |  phase 1  |  0.1     |  0.11
2      |  1      |  phase 1  |  0.11    |  0.12
...    |  ...    |  ...      |  ...     |  ...
36000  |  1      |  phase 1  |  0.14    |  0.16
36001  |  2      |  phase 2  |  0.11    |  0.20
...    |  ...    |  ...      |  ...     |  ...
72000  |  2      |  phase 2  |  0.14    |  0.16
72001  |  3      |  phase 3  |  0.11    |  0.20
...    |  ...    |  ...      |  ...     |  ...
108000 |  3      |  phase 3  |  0.16    |  0.20
108001 |  4      |  phase 4  |  0.15    |  0.20
...    |  ...    |  ...      |  ...     |  ...
144000 |  4      |  phase 4  |  0.11    |  0.22
144001 |  5      |  phase 1  |  0.11    |  0.22
...    |  ...    |  ...      |  ...     |  ...
```

I have about 20 Gigabytes of data I have to process. So I have hundreds of cycles worth of data, and I need the last 120 rows of *each cycle* to be averaged and stored in a new table. So in the above table I need rows 35880 to 36000 to be pulled out and each data column averaged and placed as a row in another table.

```
Averages
|  Cycle  |  Phase    |  Avg(data 1)  |  Avg(data 2) ... Avg(data 60)
|  1      |  phase 1  |  0.11         |  0.12
|  2      |  phase 2  |  0.11         |  0.12
|  3      |  phase 3  |  0.11         |  0.12
|  4      |  phase 4  |  0.11         |  0.12
|  5      |  phase 1  |  0.11         |  0.12
...
```

## Edit July 17th, 2020

Adding the create table statement. There is an auto-incrementing primary key column that is similar to the 'Row #' column above.

```
CREATE TABLE Raw_Data (
'Raw_data_id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
'Date' TEXT,
'Time' TEXT,
'Phase' TEXT,
'Cycle' INTEGER,
'data 1' REAL,
'data 2' REAL,
...
'data 60' REAL
);
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` in SQL is not quite the same thing as `groupby` in Pandas. In Pandas you can provide your own custom aggregation function, but in SQL you're limited to a small set of built-in aggregates (a few DBMS do let you add your own UDF aggregates, but SQLite requires you to make them in C)

Comment: Please show the definition of your `time_for_avg` function.

Comment: A small sample data set and expected results from it would be useful.

Comment: @Dai - The time_for_avg is just a constant. In this case it is 120 as I want the last 120 data points from the pandas dataframe in my groupby object.

Comment: @Shawn - I have expanded on the description in a posting update, which includes sample data and results.

Comment: @Shawn You cannot meaningfully request the "last 120 records" in SQL without first specifying an `ORDER BY` criteria. Tables in SQL do not have an inherent natural-order or row-number (SQLite internally does, but you shouldn't depend on that). From what I can tell your `Phase+Cycle` tuple is insufficient to consistently order your elements. Is your `Row#` column part of your real table definition? Please post your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Dia I have shown the CREATE TABLE statement. There is a column similar to Row #.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just the last "group"'s data, then you don't want `GROUP BY` - I think this would work instead:

#### Step 1: Find the latest `Phase+Cycle` tuple:

```
SELECT
    Phase,
    Cycle
FROM
    table
ORDER BY
    Phase,
    Cycle
LIMIT
    1
```

#### Step 2: Filter the entire set in `table` using that result:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Phase,
            Cycle
        FROM
            table
        ORDER BY
            Phase,
            Cycle
        LIMIT
            1
    ) AS q ON table.Phase = q.Phase AND table.Cycle = q.Cycle
```

#### Step 3: Aggregate processing:

You can either do the aggregation and processing in application code, if it's complicated - or by adding the SQLite-built-in aggregates directly to the query:

```
SELECT
    Phase,
    Cycle,
    AVG( data1 ) AS avg1,
    AVG( data2 ) AS avg2,
    SUM( data3 ) AS sum3,
    -- etc
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Phase,
            Cycle
        FROM
            table
        ORDER BY
            Phase,
            Cycle
        LIMIT
            1
    ) AS q ON table.Phase = q.Phase AND table.Cycle = q.Cycle
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort; however, as I elaborated on in my posting update, I require all of the Phases and Cycles to be processed and not just the last one. Is there a way to update this query to grab the last 120 rows of data? and to do it for all Cycles and Phases? Thanks so much!